# PNG file has different colours in different programs

Tags: png, file-format, gamma

I downloaded an icon from [Icons8](http://icons8.com/icons/#!/3220/plus). With their tool I recolored it to dark blue (#2c3e50). After unpacking and uploading the 48px icon I got the following result:

[image: Icon]

As you can see the color is not #2c3e50, but #738697. I was quite confused, so I opened the file with different programs (all using Windows 8.1):

Paint.NET: #2c3e50
Paint: #2c3e50
Gimp: #2c3e50
IrfanView: #2c3e50

Chrome: #738697
Firefox: #738697
Windows Picture Viewer: #738697

Does anybody knows what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

To get arround this issue I open the file using Gimp and export it as PNG. This seems to correct the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Examining the image with [TweakPNG](http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng), I can see the image contains gamma information (a `gAMA` chunk with a gamma value of 1.0).  Some image viewers respect this gamma information and apply gamma correction to the image, while others do not.

If you are happy using the command-line, you can automate the removal of things like gamma information using a tool such as [PNGOUT](http://advsys.net/ken/util/pngout.htm) - which will also optimise the compression of the file to reduce its file size.